# Changing Font Color in PyCharm "Run" pane

Tags: colors, pycharm, settings

With a dark theme chosen, the "*run*" pane (**not** the python "*console*" **nor** the "*terminal*" accessible within PyCharm) shows a very dark font such that it can barely be seen. Switching to a light theme, all is well. I've found help (within Pycharm, here, Google, and YouTube) on setting the font colors for the *editor*, *console*, and *terminal* panes, but not a thing on changing the *run-pane* colors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, I am using the [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console) plugin (in my older 5.0.6 PyCharm Pro version) which also controls the Run panes and has a fairly configurable color scheme (both background and foreground):

[image]

This is how the Run pane looks like (snapshot intentionally smudged):

[image]

Comment: Thanks it's a great tool !

Answer (score 2):

I usually just use native Editor settings in the Preferences. 
So you can try going into the :

- **Preferences** > *Editor* > *Color Scheme* > *Console Colors*
- click on **Console Colors** and use the menu on the right
- **Console** > Backgroud > select prefered color
- Click Apply to test the color
- Click OK to save changes

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work for me. I neglected to indicate in my question that I'm using the Community Edition 2017.2.3. The console-color selections seems to have no effect on the run pane. Perhaps it does in other editions/versions. What _**did**_ work for me was @Dan Cornilescu's suggestion that I use the Grep plug-in which seems to set the run-pane colors just the way I want them.

Comment: I see make sense.