# Colored words not appearing in the IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-3.6

I'm making an RPG through pycharm and i wish to run the program through the IDE. There are some words in the game that i want to be different colours. I've looked up all the solutions for this and I can't seem to find one that works. Here's what I tried last:

```
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
target="The System"
print(bcolors.WARNING + target.upper() + bcolors.ENDC)
```

and its output is [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9ifJ.jpg)
is there and fix to this?

Comment: What have you tried other than this?

Comment: Different versions of this really @Goodra

Comment: Could you include them please? May help with finding a suitable answer

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: @PRMoureu Windows 10 with Python 3.6 on Pycharm

Comment: @Goodra http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama

Comment: Please don't use RPG tag for roll playing games, it is for the RPG programming language.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy Shoot sorry totally forgot about that

Comment: @AidanChristopher not a biggie, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Maybe give [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console) a try? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46945072/changing-font-color-in-pycharm-run-pane/46947416#46947416? Donno if/how it works on Windows, tho, I'm on Linux.